# REST API: adapt a cURL POST to Powershell 5 (upload files)

Tags: powershell, curl, post

I have this cURL command that I must adapt to Powershell in order to upload different files. In order to do that, I have mandatory fields that I need use in the request.
I've tried like a dozen of different scripts, nothing works.

Can someone help me out with this?
It should be plain simple, but I am missing something.

cURL command:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer xxx" 
-F "parentDirectoryId=1" 
-F "name=AutoUpload" 
-F "contents=@C:\temp\test.pdf" 
https://url/v1/api/files?
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Invoke-RestMethod to upload jpg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42395638/how-to-use-invoke-restmethod-to-upload-jpg)

Comment: I've checked that link before posting, but my request is different @DanWilson, since it contains other parameters as well.

Comment: Then you may need to construct a `WebRequest` object instead. https://stackoverflow.com/a/45409728/3608792

Comment: I've reviewed that post as well and it didn't help. @DanWilson, perhaps you know how to write the entire script?

Answer (score 0):

This is going to depend on which version of Powershell you are using. If you have Powershell 6 you can use the simple method below which uses the form parameter. If you use another version you can use the more complicated example #4 which is outlined on the [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-6):

```
$Uri = 'https://url/v1/api/files?'
$Form = @{
    parentDirectoryId= '1'
    name = 'AutoUpload'
    contents= Get-Item -Path 'C:\temp\test.pdf'
}
$token = ConvertTo-SecureString "xxx" -AsPlainText -Force
$Result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $Uri -Method Post -Form $Form -Authentication Bearer -Token $token
```

This example uses the new Authentication and Form parameters in Invoke-RestMethod. Depending on your Authentication type, you will need either a Token or Credentials parameter with additional information. The Form parameter simplifies what was previously a complicated process for adjusting the body or URI per request.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the reply @Jordan. I've tested your script both on Powershell 5 and 6 and it doesn't work. 
Here's the response error:

Invoke-RestMethod : Cannot bind parameter 'Headers'. 
Cannot convert the "-Authorization" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Collections.IDictionary".
At line:1 char:64

Comment: I have adapted the script found on Microsoft Docs Example 4 and that doesn't do it either.

Comment: Remove the headers parameter and it should work for pwsh 6, it's a copy paste error. I'll update my code in a bit.

Comment: Jordan, here's the error I get:

Invoke-RestMethod : Cannot bind parameter 'Token'. Cannot convert the "xxx" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Security.SecureString".
At line:1 char:93

+ ... Uri $Uri -Method Post -Form $Form -Authorization Bearer -Token $token
+                                                                    ~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-RestMethod], ParameterBindingException

+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand

Comment: Secure strings are a bit complicated. The simple method is to update
`$token = "xxx"` to be `$token = (Read-Host -AsSecureString)`. You will have to type the bearer token into the host. If you don't have a problem leaving the token in plain text, you can use `$token = ConvertTo-SecureString "xxx" -AsPlainText -Force` Otherwise see [ConvertTo-SecureString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/convertto-securestring?view=powershell-6).

Comment: Thanks again. 
Invoke-RestMethod : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Authorization'.

Comment: Additionally change `-Authorization` to `-Authentication`, more copy paste issues. I've updated the answer to reflect this change.

Comment: This is just like pingpong.. perhaps we should try another communication channel and post the solution?
this is what I get now:
Invoke-RestMethod : {"type":"http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html","title":"Not Acceptable","status":406,"detail":"Unable to resolve Accept header to a representation"}