# Uploaded attachment PNG is not shown correctly

Tags: powershell, azure-devops

I use the following powershell and REST-API to upload attachment

```
class TfsHelper{
#...
  [string]UploadPng([string]$TfsProject, [string]$PngFileName) {
    $uri = "http://$organization/$TfsProject/_apis/wit/attachments?fileName=image.png&api-version=5.1"
    $strPngBase64 = [convert]::ToBase64String((Get-Content $PngFileName -Encoding byte))  
    $rtn = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method POST -Headers $this.Header `
      -Body $strPngBase64 `
      -ContentType 'application/octet-stream'
    return $rtn.url
  }
}
```

The function UploadPng executed successfully and I can also get the response  which contains the uploaded PNG url and uuid

But when I opened response url in browser to check the uploaded PNG, I found the uploaded image was not shown as expected and not same as the original one.

[image: The uploaded image shown in browser]
[image: The original png in local]

So, what`s wrong with the function UploadPng?

Comment: Why not use `Invoke-RestMethod -InFile` instead of `Get-Content` ?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42395638/how-to-use-invoke-restmethod-to-upload-jpg

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon， appreciate, but when use `-Infile` and `-ContentType 'application/octet-stream'` together, it will raise exception——"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" is not available content type for ”POST“

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon, -inFile is worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce the same issue when using the same Powershell script.

To solve this issue, you can use the powershell command: `[IO.File]::ReadAllBytes("$PngFileName")` to read the file and no need to convert it to base64. Then you can change the content type to `application/json`.

```
class TfsHelper{
#...
  [string]UploadPng([string]$TfsProject, [string]$PngFileName) {
    $uri = "http://$organization/$TfsProject/_apis/wit/attachments?fileName=image.png&api-version=5.1"
    $file = [IO.File]::ReadAllBytes("$PngFileName") 
    $rtn = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method POST -Headers $this.Header `
      -Body $file  `
      -ContentType 'application/json'
    return $rtn.url
  }
}
```

Or you can use the `-InFile` to create the attachment.

Here is PowerShell example:

```
class TfsHelper{
#...
  [string]UploadPng([string]$TfsProject, [string]$PngFileName) {
    $uri = "http://$organization/$TfsProject/_apis/wit/attachments?fileName=image.png&api-version=5.1"
    $file = Get-ChildItem -Path "filepath" 
    $rtn = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method POST -Headers $this.Header `
      -InFile $file `
      -ContentType 'application/octet-stream'
    return $rtn.url
  }
}
```

**Update:**

```
class TfsHelper{
  [string]UploadPng([string]$TfsProject, [string]$PngFileName) {
    $uri = "https://dev.azure.com/orgname/$TfsProject/_apis/wit/attachments?fileName=image.png&api-version=5.1"
    $file = Get-ChildItem -Path "$PngFileName" 
    $token = "PAT"
    $token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))
    $rtn = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method POST -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} `
      -InFile $file `
      -ContentType 'application/octet-stream'

    return $rtn.url
  }
}


$uploadpng = [TfsHelper]::new()

echo $uploadpng.UploadPng("projectname","pngpath")
```

Comment: Both solutions raise error `Content-Type 'application/x-www-
form-urlencoded' is unsupported for method 'POST'`

Comment: @zhong Can you try to run the script in my update of the answer? Check if it can work for you.

Comment: The cause of the issue could be that the Invoke-RestMethod ignore the Content type argument.  you can set the all  parameters at the same line, for example: `$rtn = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method POST -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -InFile $file -ContentType 'application/octet-stream'`

Comment: It is worked and appreciate for your guidance. The exception('application/x-www- form-urlencoded') memtioned in my previous reply, was caused by the comments between line-break ```. Sorry for my confused reply.